# CodeIgniter 4: How to access URI placeholder values in the Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

How to get Details Message Inbox on CodeIgniter 4?

My Code :

**Views**

`<a href="<?= base_url() ?>/mailbox/baca-inbox/<?= $getMail->getNumber(); ?>">Baca</a>`

**Routes**

`$routes->get('/mailbox/baca-inbox/(:num)', 'Mailbox::readMail/$1');`

**Controllers**

```
public function readMail( this number of inbox mail )
    {
        $getDetailsMessage     = $this->mailboxInbox->getMessage( this number of inbox mail );

        $data = [
            'title' => 'Baca Email Ci 4',
            'inbox' => $getDetailsMessage
        ];
        return view('readmail', $data);
    }
```

**I'm confused about how to retrieve the inbox number**

How to get number of inbox mail?
I'm learning CodeIgniter 4

Answer (score 0):

Problem Fixed by code :

**View :**

```
<a href="<?= base_url() ?>/mailbox/baca-inbox/<?php $noMessage = $getMail->getNumber(); echo $noMessage; ?>"> Baca Email</a>
```

**Routes :**

```
$routes->get('/mailbox/baca-inbox/(:num)', 'Mailbox::readMail/$1');
```

**Controller :**

```
public function readMail($noMessage)
    {
        $getDetailsMessage     = $this->mailboxInbox->getMessage($noMessage);

        $data = [
            'title' => 'Baca Email Ci 4',
            'inbox' => $getDetailsMessage
        ];
        return view('readmail', $data);
    }
```

***Thank you for participating in answering my questions.***